# Problems with calling from strings.xml

Tags: android, string

I am having a problem calling string values from the `strings.xml` resource in Android. The `strings.xml` file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="name1">contact_name1</string>
    <string name="phone1">contact_phone1</string>
</resources>
```

And the code calling for the string values is:

```
private final String NAME1  = getString(R.string.name1);
private final String PHONE1 = getString(R.string.phone1);
```

I am calling for the strings from my `main.java` where I `extend Activity`, so I have the context. The problem is that when I run the app (physical device (EVO) or an emulator (API Levels 5 - 8) I get a `NullPointerException` at the line where the first `getString()` call is located. I have been over Google's documentation, a number of posts here and at AndDev.org with no change to the end result. Will some one please tell me whats wrong before I pull all of my hair out!? The `strings.xml` file is in the standard location (`<project_folder><res><values>` directory) in the same package as the rest of the app.

Comment: @Nic Strong You mean from LogCat? or the raw text file from the device?

Comment: Be sure that you didn't inadvertently import android.R (or, if you did, fully qualify R with your package name).

Comment: See sugarynugs answer. Calling methods in the class body outside a static initializer is equivalent to having them in a constructor, since the Java compiler will simply generate field initialization code for those lines and insert them in the constructor in their order of declaration. Since the context isn't fully initialized at that point, however, you will see erroneous behavior. Therefore, do all initialization that requires a `Context` in `onCreate`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't call `getString` from what is in effect the constructor of an `Activity` as the context does not exist.  You will need to remove the `final` keyword and assign the member variables in `onCreate()`.

Comment: AWESOME! That worked like a charm, I got another question that I can't seem to get a clear answer like this for. @sugarynugs, would you mind taking a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751609/writing-to-the-internal-private-storage-in-android-updated-2-9-11

Comment: @Kingsolmn.  I've had a look and left a comment.

Answer (score 1):

use the below line in onCreate()

```
final String NAME1  = (getResources().getString(R.string.name1));
```

Comment: getResources().getString() is equivalent to getString()

Comment: Figured out that while I was going for global class scope I was trying to define the constant values outside of the `onCreate()` method, so the context was not defined yet.