# App Crashes on Launch, Trying to see if file exist's for login screen

Tags: java, android, file, crash

I'm creating a Class that checks to see if the file has been created (Has username and passwords.) and if it does it creates an intent to go to another class to read the data and check it againts a server via FTP. For some reason, I can't get it to work, I've tried everything and read every single web page I could, but no luck.

My Code:

```
public class LogIn extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button send;
EditText user;
EditText pass;
CheckBox staySignedIn;
FileOutputStream Fos;
String a;
String b;
String string = a;
String string2 = b;

String FILENAME = "userandpass";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogIn);
    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTuser);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTpassword);
    staySignedIn = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Cbstay);
    send.setOnClickListener(this);

    if (staySignedIn.isChecked()) {

        String a = user.getText().toString();
        String b = pass.getText().toString();
        File f = new File(FILENAME);
        try {
            Fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Fos.write(string.getBytes());
            Fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(FILENAME);
        if(file.exists());
        Intent i = new Intent(LogIn.this, ChatService.class);
    }

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bLogIn:
        if (pass.length() == 0)
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Try to type in your username and password again!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else if (user.length() == 0)
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Try to type in your username and password again!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else {

            String u = user.getText().toString();
            String p = pass.getText().toString();
            Bundle send = new Bundle();
            send.putString("key", u);
            send.putString("key1", p);
            Intent a = new Intent(LogIn.this, logincheck.class);
            a.putExtra("key", u);
            a.putExtra("key1", p);
            startActivity(a);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Were signing you in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            break;
        }
    }

}
}
```

LogCat:

```
 01-19 11:37:17.601: W/dalvikvm(4411): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught  exception (group=0x4001d800)
    01-19 11:37:17.621: E/AndroidRuntime(4411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-19 11:37:17.621: E/AndroidRuntime(4411): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.gta5news.bananaphone/com.gta5news.bananaphone.LogIn}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-19 11:37:17.621: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    01-19 11:37:17.621: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    01-19 11:37:17.621: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    01-19 11:37:17.621: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    01-19 11:37:17.621: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-19 11:37:17.621: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    01-19 11:37:17.621: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    01-19 11:37:17.621: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-19 11:37:17.621: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    01-19 11:37:17.621: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    01-19 11:37:17.621: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
   01-19 11:37:17.621: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):    
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native  Method)
    01-19 11:37:17.621: E/AndroidRuntime(4411): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-19 11:37:17.621: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at  com.gta5news.bananaphone.LogIn.onCreate(LogIn.java:55)
    01-19 11:37:17.621: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    01-19 11:37:17.621: E/AndroidRuntime(4411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Comment: This is line 55 according to eclipse Fos.write(string.getBytes());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If line 55 is

```
Fos.write(string.getBytes());
```

then either `Fos` or `string` is uninitialized. Given that `string` is initialized to `a` which is itself uninitialized, that explains it. You need to assign a proper value to `string`.

Comment: How would I go around do that? I already said in the code that string & string 1 equals the two edit text fields.

Comment: No, you didn't. At the point where you make the assignment `string = a`, `a` is `null`.

Comment: Oh, I get you, so what could I do to assign a value to string?

Answer (score 0):

```
Fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

It seems for some reason openFileOutput returning null which makes Fos null, which is throwing NullPointerException.

Add

```
if(Fos != null) { 
 Fos.write(string.getBytes());
 Fos.close();
} check.
```

OR catch `NullpointerException`.

Comment: Yes! That worked, but my string isn't being saved to the file or the file isn't being created.

Comment: It seems File is not being created, may be you don't have permission required?

Comment: See this link, it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751609/writing-to-the-internal-private-storage-in-android-updated-2-6-12

Comment: What the permission? I only have the "Write to external drive" permission, I guess that's not the correct one, what one do I need?