# Copy file from the internal to the external storage in Android

Tags: java, android, file-io, copy, android-external-storage

My app (*Android API 15*) makes a picture and stores it in the internal memory's folder. Now, I want to copy this file to another folder inside of the external storage, e.g. `/sdcard/myapp`. I tried the following approaches:

**Approach #1:**

```java
private void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {

    File from = new File(src.getPath());
    File to = new File(dst.getPath());
    from.renameTo(to);
}
```

---

**Approach #2:**

```java
private void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {

    FileChannel inChannel = null;
    FileChannel outChannel = null;

    try {
        inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
        outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    } finally {
        if (inChannel != null)
            inChannel.close();
        if (outChannel != null)
            outChannel.close();
    }
}
```

---

**Approach #3:**

```java
private void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(src);

    if (!dst.exists()) {
        dst.mkdir();
    }

    if (!dst.canWrite()) {
        System.out.print("CAN'T WRITE");
        return;
    }

    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(dst);
    FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
    inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();
}
```

---

None of these methods doesn't solve my task. In checked a number of related topics, and the only suggestion I found is to verify the persistence of

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml` and it does persist.

The ***approach #1*** finishes the execution, but no folder and files are copied.

In the ***approach #2***, the app fails with the exception `java.lang.NullPointerException` at `outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();`, but the object dst is not a null.

In the ***approach #3***, I decided to verify if the destination object exists and it creates a folder if needed, but when I check if I can write, the check returns `false`.

I tried a couple of additional approaches, which succeeded to create an empty folder, but no files are really copied.

Since this is my very first step towards Android, I feel I miss some small thing. Please, point me, how to copy a file from one folder to another folder in Android, including file moving from internal to external memory.

Comment: maybe path problems?

Comment: @Proxytype, regarding the path, I do it this way: `String dstPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "myapp" + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
File dst = new File(dstPath);`. Should my destination path include the name of the file or just folder? Why `new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();` returns null even if `dst` is filled and there is free space on a storage?

Comment: try to create the destination file before write to it, File dest = new File(path); check if it was created on the device... also give it name..  File to = new File(dst.getPath() + "/myname");

Comment: I already do it, and even more: `if (!dst.exists()) {isCreated = dst.mkdir();}`, after this code the variable `isCreated` is equal to `false`. It's strange, why I can create the initial file, but not copy it to another folder, even can't create a folder.

Comment: is the internal path include the data directory? follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751609/writing-to-the-internal-private-storage-in-android-updated-2-6-12

Comment: I use approach 2, and get the destination path like this: `context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath()`  Presumably you could add directories onto that and call `mkdirs()`.  Have you called mkdirs on the output directory (not including filename)?  Do you end up with that directory and it's empty, or no directory, or what?

Comment: Are you taking picture with existing (bulit-in, Android default) camera app?

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić, I'm not sure if it can be considered as using of the default camera app, but I'm using the default `Camera` class-based object and call the `takePicture()` method in order to shot the image. How it can be related to the problem of file copy?

Comment: I wanted to reproduce the problem in the same environment. That is why I asked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved my issue. The problem was in the destination path, in the original code:

```java
File dst = new File(dstPath);
```

the variable `dstPath` had the full destination path, including the name of the file, which is wrong. Here is the correct code fragment:

```java
String dstPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "myApp" + File.separator;
File dst = new File(dstPath);

exportFile(pictureFile, dst);
```

---

```java
private File exportFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {

    //if folder does not exist
    if (!dst.exists()) {
        if (!dst.mkdir()) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File expFile = new File(dst.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    FileChannel inChannel = null;
    FileChannel outChannel = null;

    try {
        inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
        outChannel = new FileOutputStream(expFile).getChannel();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    } finally {
        if (inChannel != null)
            inChannel.close();
        if (outChannel != null)
            outChannel.close();
    }

    return expFile;
}
```

Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Thanks. Your way is much faster than writing buffers.

Answer (score 7):

Kotlin https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/copy-to.html

```
    // video is some file in internal storage
    val to = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/destination.file")
    if(to.exists().not()) {
        to.createNewFile()
    }
    video.copyTo(to, true)
```

Comment: Will this get stored under downloads ?